# How can I document mexFunction parameters with Doxygen?

Tags: matlab, doxygen

Every mexFunction has the same prototype:

```
void mexFunction(int nlhs, mxArray *plhs[], int nrhs, const mxArray *prhs[])
```

We could document this like a normal function:

```
void mexFunction(
    int nlhs, /**< number of left hand arguments **/
    mxArray *plhs[], /**< left hand arguments **/
    int nrhs, /**< number of right hand arguments **/
    const mxArray *prhs[] /**< right hand arguments **/
    )
```

But this tells us nothing about the actual arguments.

Is there any better option than just documenting as:

```
/**
* \details
* inputs:
*    prhs[0] - blah blah
*    prhs[1] - blah 
*
* outputs:
*    plhs[0] - yadda yadda
**/
```

Bad examples found on net:

- http://fossies.org/dox/FreeMat-4.2-Source/levmar_8c_source.html
- http://fossies.org/dox/getfem-4.3/gfm__mex_8c_source.html
- http://doxygen.scilab.org/master_wg/d9/d6c/temptst_8cpp_source.html

No good examples found.

Comment: Who came up with "s" to represent "arrays" anyway?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible solution, but the syntax for bullets is picky, and the output has a lot of excess white space (I may still accept someone else's solution):

```
void mexFunction(
    int nlhs, /**< number of left hand arguments (3 expected) */
    mxArray *plhs[], /**< left hand arguments, expected elements:
                      *    - [0] - blah
                      *    - [1] - blah blah blah blah, blah blah blah
                                   blah blah
                      *    - [2] - yadda yadda  */
    int nrhs, /**< number of right hand arguments (0 expected) */
    const mxArray *prhs[] /**< right hand arguments (no elements expected) */
)
```

Comment: Although more common perhaps to have several right hand arguments and 1 left hand...